# How to I crop an image based on a bounding box in the image (programatically)?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, gd

I'm building a web application that needs to be able to crop an image based on the location of a 4-sided shape with a white border (and no fill) contained in the image. All images uploaded by users are going to be dark so they shouldn't interfere with the algorithm to find the bounding box. This part of the application should be able to handle all types of quadrilaterals and will stretch whatever is contained within the white-bordered shape to fit a square.

My lazy rendition in Photoshop: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJjoL.png

I'm using Laravel to build this application (LAMP stack). I'm looking at libraries such as ImageMagick and GD but I'm still new to programatically editing images. Are there specific functions in IM or GD that I could call to help me build this part of the application? Are there better PHP libraries that have the ability to do this? I'm not asking for code necessarily; I just want to know what tools I should start with before I build this.

Answer (score 1):

Imagemagick can be used for this type of application if I understand what you're asking.  To change the perspective of an image, look into:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective

To crop images after distorting, look into:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop

It would be easy to make a bash loop to accomplish these two tasks.  Something like this:

```
 ## first distort the images

 for i in *.jpg ##or whatever format you have (.tiff, pdf, etc..) 
 do 
 convert $i -distort Perspective out_file.png ## where you give coordinates into the perspective method
 done

 ## now to crop the distorted images
 for i in *.png 
 do
 convert $i -crop out_file.jpg ## where you give the coordinates of the new rectangle to the crop method
 done
```

The code above is just a STARTING point and would need to be populated according to the links I mentioned above.  Happy scripting!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into OpenCV for recognizing the rectagle.  GD and image magic are good at editing images using filters, but they don't do a lot (or any?) of object detection.

See: https://github.com/ProGM/OpenCV-for-PHP/wiki/Installation-guide